# XPath to get youtube video c#

Tags: c#, xpath, youtube, windows-phone, word-wrap

The code works, but I can not get the exact link to the page, and that way I do not return anything, it returns an exception that happens because the path does not find anything. [The page is as follows](http://www.unnu.com/jason-derulo/the-other-side), and I need to get the video that this path at the "SelectSingleNode".

please help me to build the correct XPath to get the link of the video from youtube.

My source code:

```
private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
    {
      var data = e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html/head/link")
           .Attributes["href"].Value.ToString();

           MessageBox.Show(data);
           Uri obj = new Uri(data);
           Web.Source = obj;
           Web.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

If you click "Inspect Element" on this page, you will find the youtube link that way I describe in "SelectSingleNode". I just left there so you can find the link and help me, but that string is not correct.

This code gets another link. I need to get the real link of youtube video. I try this XPath string but now works: `"//html/body/div/iframe/html/head"`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple child LINK elements in the HEAD. You need to identify via the which one you want, similar to this: `e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html/head/link[@id='someId']")`

Comment: the links dont have any Id.

Comment: can the LINK element be identified uniquely by any attributes? or is it always the nth child LINK element?

Comment: The link has no other attribute outside the rel = "canonical", that's why I'm in trouble. Click on the website and then click on the page with the right mouse button and select "inspect element" so you can find where is the link.

Comment: try `e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html/head/link[[last()]");`
it looks like it is the last child LINK element in the HEAD element

Comment: you can see that after the iframe has a "# document" and beneath it is <! Document html> again ... I'm thinking it's because of that, but do not know how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

How about `//iframe[contains(@src, "youtube")]//link[@rel="canonical"]`?

Returns `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byp94CCWKSI"/>`.

---

I am guessing based off of the method signature that you are using HtmlAgilityPack... which does not retrieve the content of IFrames.  You will need to issue a separate request for the content of the IFrame:

```
var hwMainPage = new HtmlWeb();
var hdMainPage = hwMainPage.Load(@"http://www.unnu.com/jason-derulo/the-other-side");
var iframeUri = hdMainPage.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//iframe[contains(@src, \"youtube\")]")
    .Attributes["src"].Value;

var hwIframe = new HtmlWeb();
var hdIframe = hwIframe.Load(iframeUri);
var videoCanonicalUri = hdIframe.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//link[@rel=\"canonical\"]")
    .Attributes["href"].Value;

// videoCanonicalUri == http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byp94CCWKSI
```

Comment: @LuizNegrini, Then you should post the implementation of XPath you are working with as it is evidently nonstandard.  Something is obviously different.

Comment: Yes use the HtmlAgilityPack, but bounce back to the platform I'm working on is Windows Phone. The load method is asynchronous.

Comment: Very strange, I put a MessageBox to see what was the content of the string it opens with the correct video url in primeio code block. But when I give the OK one exception saying it is null.

Comment: forgot to tell you, I need to get only the url of the video, do not download the video itself. I go to open it in a webBrowser.

Comment: The link that is obtained with this path is not correct, the error always when I rewrite a hand in the address bar of the web browser. Says that the video does not exist.

Comment: @LuizNegrini, the link you posted returns http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvtxgntyfms, as expected.  The video is indeed UNAVAILABLE, but it is located properly.  A video being unavailable is set by the publisher's preferences towards embedding or geographic boundaries.  Re: WP, If you are running on WP8, you will need to convert it to asynchronous to run on WP8, but the XPATH will remain the same.  Re: downloading, I never download the video (which would require quite a bit more work).

Comment: I understand what you mean. And I'm in version 7.1 but still could not resolve that url of the video I can usually pick up, but what needs to be done is to take what you have after the # document node that there is actual video and if you copy the link in your address bar it opens correctly.